# Apple developer non-disclosure

Tags: discussion, answers, comments

I see a lot of questions regarding Xcode 6 and iOS 8 beta software releases.

If a Stack Overflow user has access to pre-release software, in theory they are registered developers, and are obliged to abide by the non disclosure agreement (NDA) that we all agreed to when we became a registered developer.

Forgive me for being a nark, but are these questions about Xcode 6 and iOS 8 beta software therefore in breach of the NDA?

So therefore I also ask whether the only suitable forum for discussion about these questions the Apple Developer Forums?

Finally, and if all my evil narkyness is true, then what should a good Stack Overflower write when we come across such a question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Standard disclaimer: I'm not a lawyer. This advice is not legal advice and should not be taken as such.*

Technically, no.

[Stack Exchange is not responsible for upholding other companies' NDAs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94488/258672), but whether *you* do is entirely up to you. As soon as there are new beta releases, people tweet about it and Apple news sites go crazy, with people blatantly violating NDAs in the comments.

Apple has [partly lifted the NDA this year](http://oleb.net/blog/2014/06/apple-lifted-beta-nda/), allowing developers to freely discuss *technical information and tools* that have been announced (which includes Xcode 6, iOS 8, and OS X Yosemite), but posting screenshots and pre-release reviews still violates the agreement.

There is a [similar discussion](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1331/can-i-ask-about-not-yet-publicly-released-os?cb=1) (also [here](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1712/are-ios-8-and-os-x-yosemite-questions-ok?cb=1)) going on at [Ask Different](//apple.stackexchange.com), but the sentiment there is different because that site is for Apple power users, not Apple developers, so questions are less likely to be about technical information and more likely to violate the NDA.

As always, the Apple Developer Forums is the safest place to ask for technical support, as it's for registered Apple developers only, but it's certainly allowed here.

The best thing to do is read through the [agreement itself](https://developer.apple.com/programs/terms/ios/standard/ios_program_standard_agreement_20140602.pdf) if you're in doubt.